# Outlook doesn't recognize margin

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am making an e-mail template with html and css. After finishing the template and inserting it into Outlook, the containers with the text are unfortunately not in the position I have predefined. To put the containers in the place I wanted I used the "margin" element in my code. But unfortunately Outlook does not recognize it. Does anyone know how I can set the heights of these boxes without using the "margin"? I've tried using padding but it's not working. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: How I setted everything, if you open this HTML in your normal explorer it looks like this]

*How I setted everything, if you open this HTML in your normal explorer it looks like this*

[image: How it is looking like on Outlook]

*How it is looking like on Outlook*

*The code for one of the boxes to move it inside the circle, I used "margin"

```
<table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left"
                    style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left; Margin-top: -290px; postion: relative">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="es-m-p20b" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:225px">
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFF3EC"
                          style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#fff3ec"
                          role="presentation">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:15px;Margin:0">
                              <p
                                style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:tahoma, verdana, segoe, sans-serif;line-height:17px;color:#000000;font-size:14px;">
                                <br><strong>Probe Text<br>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                              <p
                                style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:tahoma, verdana, segoe, sans-serif;line-height:17px;color:#000000;font-size:14px;text-align:left">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                                tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br><br></p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: why `Margin` and not `margin`?

Comment: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/outlook-com-does-support-margins/     --------- Hi, this article suggested the use of "Margin" instead of "margin"

Comment: It's an article from 2015. Most likely the people from Outlook have fixed their HTML/CSS stripping logic to be case-insensitive now. :/

Comment: Hi, yes but it's still not working. I tried it both ways

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=margin negative margins are not supported in outlook. Creating HTML mails means slicing graphics like it's 1990 to get overlapping effects like this.

Comment: See https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position

Answer (score 2):

That is because Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. It applies its own rules to the elements and styles. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Your new posts duplicate the existing question.